# Insert a backslash before special character in a string using python or shell script

Tags: python, shell

Is it possible to insert a backslash when a special character appears on string ?

Raw String:
`echo "The string is: Ytds^&4"`

Output expected:
`echo "The string is: Ytds\^\&4"`

Can I use python or shell.

Comment: It depends what you consider to be a "special" character.  Python provides a `shlex.quote` function that does escaping based on the rules for Unix shells.

Comment: Note that `^` is not special on noninteractive UNIX shells; it's only special on Windows (or shells with history expansion turned on, but that's off-by-default in scripts so you don't need to worry about it).

Comment: Also, `&` doesn't need to be escaped on UNIX when it's inside a double-quoted string; the quotes are already escaping enough.

Comment: ...so what's the actual use case here? The escaping you're asking for is not POSIX-compliant; how to do _Windows_-compatible escaping should probably be asked as a Windows-specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a manual chain of `.replace()`, which would be messy.

You could also just use a function like this:

```
str_ = "Y^541" 


def change(string: str, characters): 
    for character in characters:
        string = string.replace(character, "\\" + character)
    return string


print(change(str_, "!@#$%^&*()")) # output: Y\^541
```

The argument `characters` should be a string of all the characters which are considered as special, and it does a loop to replace each of those characters with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the following will produce exactly the required output:

```
print('The string is: Ytds\^\&4')
```

This is because neither the caret nor the ampersand are escapable characters and therefore the backslash is interpreted literally giving this output:

```
The string is: Ytds\^\&4
```

Comment: I think OP could be passing this string into a function where these characters have significance, like in regex, so they have to put a backslash before it. They could also just have to do this for a string that is of a high length.

Comment: @thirdsandfourths My answer is based on the information contained in the question and not supposition